# Onion URL dont respond with apache hidden service

Tags: apache, tor

I configured a hidden service with this tutorial http://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en

Tor has restarted, the files (hostname and private key) are created. Apache works on localhost, but I cant join the onion URL in my browser.
My browser is configured with Tor proxy.

I don't find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. I'd recommend asking people from tor.stackexchange.com
2. I think you should double-check your paths, your read/write permissions for those paths, and the ports apache on localhost uses and how they're redirected.